# py4j failing to run in Docker container

Tags: java, python, docker, py4j

I'm trying to run the [Getting Started](https://www.py4j.org/getting_started.html) app from a Docker container and I'm running into the following error.

> py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:25333)

I haven't changed any settings on either side of the gateway.

My Dockerfile is below.

```
# start building off a base image with JDK already installed
FROM java:openjdk-8-jdk-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache python3
RUN apk add --no-cache py-pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5001

CMD ["python", "server.py"]
```

Port `5001` is for my application server which instantiates the JavaGateway.

Comment: Is Java server running on your host machine?

Comment: Java is running but the Gateway is not

Comment: Try `docker run --net="host" <image>`. This will make the container share the same network as your local machine.

Comment: No luck unfortunately

Comment: Check these - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664994/py4j-protocol-py4jnetworkerror-an-error-occurred-while-trying-to-connect-to-th and https://github.com/bartdag/py4j/issues/262.  You may have to use the `--net="host" option in conjunction with the solutions mentioned in the 2 links

Comment: @Shiva thanks but I have already tried those solutions